# Is there someone who can explain this? Because I am beginner in programming python I could not understand well

Tags: python

```
sum=0
for i in range(1,10):
  if(i%2==0):
    continue
  sum=sum+i
print(sum)
```

The result is 25

Can anybody explain me this please?

Comment: You shouldn't use the names of built-in Python functions like `sum` as variable names.

Comment: Python tutor is really good and helpful for visualizing what's happening in the code. And it's a good way for learning, here's a link to your code to see how it works http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=sum%3D0%0Afor%20i%20in%20range%281,10%29%3A%0A%20%20if%28i%252%3D%3D0%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20continue%0A%20%20sum%3Dsum%2Bi%0Aprint%28sum%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=30&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(1,10)`  returns a sequence of numbers from  `1 to 9` . `total`is the variable to count the sum of odds numbers from `1 to 9.`.To check even number the condition is `i % 2 == 0` where `%` gives the remainder of `i / 2`. Whenever the condition `i % 2 == 0` is `True`, python returns the control to the beginning of the `for` loop skipping the remaining statements. The `continue` statement rejects all the remaining statements in the current iteration of the `for` loop and sends the control back to the top of the `for` loop.

When `i % 2  != 0`. total is added to the number `i`.
Finally, after the `for` loop ends.
The total `25` is printed.

Answer (score 2):

One way to see what's happening is to print inside the loop:

```
sum=0
for i in range(1,10):
  if(i%2==0):
    continue
  print(f"+{i}") # <-- Add this line to print +i
  sum=sum+i
print(sum)
```

> +1
>
> +3
>
> +5
>
> +7
>
> +9
>
> 25

The `continue` line is skipping even `i` and the sum of the odd is 25.